# Make iframe 100% height on blogger website

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a blogspot website (blogger.com) and i created a new page to embeds outside URL to my blog using html iframe
when i set width:100%; to the iframe it works fine and the frame take the 100% of width
my problem with height
i want to make iframe height 100% and the iframe can change the height of the page depends on content when user browsing.
i tried a lot of solutions on the internet and it all didn't work with me
here is the link for the page: https://fortestonly5.blogspot.com/2022/07/blog-post.html

```
<style>
.container {
height:100%;
}

.item {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <iframe class="item" scrolling="no" src="https://motatwer.website/show-compare?first_phone=53&seconde_phone=2" >
</iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The container of the `iframe` must have a position other than `static`. Give it a position of `absolute` or `relative` and try again.

Comment: it's not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and added a line in your `item` css

```
.item {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

It's working that you want.

Comment: hello Mushfiqur Rahman , thanks for helping but when i aply it it didn't work fine and i made a preview for you.. https://fortestonly5.blogspot.com/2022/07/table-border-collapse-collapse-width100.html

Comment: then make position fixed for your iframe. you can test it here: https://jsbin.com/yitinepoyi/edit?html,output